# Angularjs ng-init in select doesn't work

Tags: html, angularjs

I have simple select tag:

```
<select ng-model="newItem" ng-options="pr.id + ') ' for pr in products track by pr.id"
                ng-init="newItem=products[0]"/>
```

I just want to preselect first value of products array, but it doesn't work.

Comment: post your products json

Comment: do you get products from an http request asynchronously ?

Comment: `$http.get("/products")
        .then(
            function (response) {
                $scope.products = response.data;
                console.log("Success");
            },
            function (errResponse) {
                console.log(errResponse.statusText);
            }
        );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this

(i) Add a **`ng-if`** since your products are getting loaded asynchronously,

```
<div ng-if = products.length > 0>
  <select ng-model="newItem" ng-options="pr.id + ') ' for pr in products track by pr.id"
ng-init="newItem=products[0]"/>
</div>
```

(ii) Assign the initial value inside your response,

```
$http.get("/products") .then( function (response) {
  $scope.products = response.data; 
  console.log("Success");
  $scope.newItem = $scope.products[0];
 }, 
function (errResponse) { console.log(errResponse.statusText); } );
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works. I understood, that html renders before controller executes, so it can't load data.